# Get a prefabs file location in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

What I am trying to do is in my `Start()` method of a prefab `GameObject` in my scene is I want to get the location of where this prefab is as a string but I cannot figure out how to do this.

Example of how I am using this:
I put a Sword Prefab `GameObject` in my scene and on `Start()` I would like to get the file directory of where this `GameObject` is in my project.

Comment: You only want to do this in the Editor?

Comment: @Programmer How I was trying to figure this out I wasn't extending Editor but Monobehavior.  I thought I could use the void Start() and get the file location of this Prefab GameObject.

Comment: I don't think you answered the question. Do you want to do this from the Editor or from Mobile and standalone build. I can show a way to do it in editor only

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand. But I think Editor is what I am looking for.  Maybe your way could shed some light and it might be what I am looking for :).

Comment: wouldn't you just drag it in as a inspector variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include `using UnityEditor;`

**NOTE**: This will only work if the prefab is to to public.

Then use `AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath` to get the path of the prefab.

```
public GameObject prefab;
void Start(){
    string prefabPath = AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath(prefab);
    Debug.Log("Path: " + prefabPath);
}
```

**Edit**:

I did some experiment with `PrefabUtility.GetPrefabType`, `PrefabUtility.GetPrefabObject` and `PrefabUtility.GetPrefabParent`. `PrefabUtility.GetPrefabParent` solved the problem. You don't need to make the prefab **public** with `PrefabUtility.GetPrefabParent`.

```
void Start()
{
    GameObject prefab = GameObject.Find("PrebabTest");
    Object GameObject2 = PrefabUtility.GetPrefabParent(prefab);
    string prefabPath = AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath(GameObject2);
    Debug.Log("Path: " + prefabPath);
}
```

Comment: I actually had something very similar but I guess how I was trying to get this to work is instead of the public GameObject variable I was trying to set gameObject as the prefab in ASsetDatabase.GetAssetPath(prefab).  So I guess this only works when you have a public variable?

Comment: Yes, I just verified it. It only work if it is a public variable. So `GameObject prefab = GameObject.Find("PrebabTest");
 string prefabPath = AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath(prefab);` **failed**.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @JoeyL I just discovered something. I modified my answer. Take a look at it. You are welcome.

Comment: Potentially important caveat: this will work in the editor, but not in published builds. Hopefully that isn't a problem.

Comment: @rutter That's not a problem because I told him that in his  question comment section.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this question is already quite old but I felt the need for adding a runtime use-case.

The AssetDatabase solution is working but as pointed out it works in the editor. If you need to prefeb path in runtime, there is way to go around this. As scriptable objects are not bound to the unity runtime, you could get the asset paths in a scriptable object. Then in runtime you can reference to this 'stored' asset path.

Note: if you want to instantiate the gameobject again in runtime, make sure to put your prefab in your Resources folder and use: `Resources<GameObject>.Load(assetPath);` (make sure to not include the file identifier in the relative asset path)

```
[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "Data", menuName = "SO/UI/BuildItemData", order = 1)]
public class BuildItemData : ScriptableObject
{
    public GameObject prefab;
    public string assetPath;
    
    #if UNITY_EDITOR
        void Awake() {
            assetPath = GetAssetPath(prefab);
        }

        public static string GetAssetPath(GameObject prefab) {
            string guid;
            long file;

            string path = null;

            if(AssetDatabase.TryGetGUIDAndLocalFileIdentifier(prefab, out guid, out file)) {
                path = AssetDatabase.GUIDToAssetPath(guid);
            }

            return path;
        }
    #endif
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get complete path from transform

```
public static string GetGameObjectPath(Transform transform)
{
    string path = transform.name;
    while (transform.parent != null)
    {
        transform = transform.parent;
        path = transform.name + "/" + path;
    }
    return path;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find prefab variant of an instance you should use

```
PrefabUtility.GetCorrespondingObjectFromSource(YourPrefabInstance)
```

If you want  to find orginal prefab of an instance you should use

```
PrefabUtility.GetCorrespondingObjectFromOriginalSource(YourPrefabInstance)
```

It will work only in Editor mode.