# How to know image is used in which prefab

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How to know which image is used in a prefabs? In the project (modified from a project on Ray Wenderlich) below, I have an image named `cat.png`. I use it in `MyPrefab.prefab`. Suppose that I'm not the project creator, how can I find out which prefab each image came from?

[image]

Comment: Did my solution work?

Comment: +1 for your answer because I have other knowledge. But it is not answer for my question. I my case, I has no Prefab object on scene. I has only know about `cat.png` image in the "Project" panel, and I want to know which Prefab use that image

Answer (score 5):

This has been answered [before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36850596/3785314). You can find it easily by using code. Just put the code below in the `Start()` function and click Play then stop. It will show you the Prefab the GameObject/cat picture belongs to.

```
   void Start()
   {
        GameObject prefab = GameObject.Find("cat");
        Object GameObject2 = UnityEditor.PrefabUtility.GetPrefabParent(prefab);
        string prefabPath = UnityEditor.AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath(GameObject2);
        Debug.Log("Path: " + prefabPath);
    }
```

OR without Code:

Select the object/cat from the hierarchy then on the Inspector on the right, click `Select` and the prefab name will be displayed and selected in the Project tab.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you click on your prefab, and go to the inspector, there should be a `Sprite Renderer` component. In it, there will a variable called `Sprite` and then your sprite next to it. If you click it (or double click, I forget which) it should highlight in your project.

Comment: You mean you know which Prefab and find image. But I mean I know image and find Prefab use that image